# How to check in a while statement if a variable is not a character but an integer and not greater than n?

Tags: bash, while-loop, integer, string-comparison

I only can figure out how to check if a variable is not a character.

This works:

```
read o
while [[ ! $o =~ -?[0-9]+ ]]; do
    echo wrong
    read o
done
```

But I want to check in **one** while statement, if it's not a character but an integer **and** greater *( I want `>` not `>=` )* than n.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
read o
while [[ ! $o =~ -?[0-9]+ ]] && [[ $o > "2" ]] ; do
    echo wrong
    read o
done
```

Why doesn't this work?

Any response is welcome!

Comment: What is your input ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet That's the goal: `read o` reads user input.

Comment: Should it be `while not an integer OR less or equal than 2` ?

Comment: Replace `>` by `-gt`.

Comment: My initial point was you cannot simply states "it does not work" without explaining how you test your program (e.g. what do you input when you test), and both current and expected results

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The first `[[ ... ]]` check if it is no integer and if so, it's wrong. The second should `[[ ... ]]` check if the integer is `>2`, if so it's wrong.

Comment: @Cyrus No, that also won't work.

Comment: In this case, replace `&&`  with `||`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Maybe I didn't understand you, but this is a part of a script, which check user input. The first example is working, the second not.

Comment: As a side note, it would be easier to check if the input is `0`, `1` or `2`, and report an error otherwise

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet As I tried to explain, this is not the task.

Answer (score 0):

As @GillesGouaillardet and @Cyrus mentioned one problem was to asume to use `&&`.

The other issue have been the double quotes.

Finaly this works:

```
read o
while [[ ! $o =~ -?[0-9]+ ]] || [[ $o > 2 ]] ; do
    echo wrong
    read o
done
```

Thank you very much to all.

Comment: Did you test it with `10`?

Comment: Ok great. On most systems though, 8 and 9 is rejected while 10 is accepted.

Comment: I can not say anything about this. I am still wondering why I have to use `||` instead of `&&`, but it works.

Comment: With `||` the second condition is ignored when the first condition is false. You want an error in to different situations: when is is not in integer and also when i is an integer but is not greater than 2 (so the second condition needs refactoring).

Comment: @WalterA Nice, now I got it. I spent four hours with it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You still want `-gt` instead of `>` in the second test. You don't want lexicographical comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Think positive.

```
while read -r o; do
   if [[ $o =~ -?[0-9]+ ]] && [[ $o -gt 3 ]]; then
      break
   fi
   echo "Wrong"
done
echo "I like your o=$o"
```

I used `-gt` and not `>`, because I want to accept `10`.

Comment: Yes @thatotherguy also mentioned this. But I cannot say anything about that, because for me `>` works and that is what I need. I don't know if or how `-gt` and `>` gives different outcome on different systems for this task.

Comment: In my case `>` will compare strings: `"3" > "11" > "1"` and `11 -gt 3 -gt 1`.

Comment: I think this depends on my script which is invoked via an alias, containing `set -f`, like `f . *.*` and inside the script an array will be filled via `find` command. But however, finally I have a solution that works. Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can use the `(( ))` construct. It expects an arithmetic expression; in an arithmetic expression, a non-integer evaluates to zero:

```
$ o=3
$ (( o > 3 )) && echo "Greater" || echo "Not greater or not a number"                                        
Not greater or not a number  
$ o=4                 
$ (( o > 3 )) && echo "Greater" || echo "Not greater or not a number"                                        
Greater                      
$ o=abc               
$ (( o > 3 )) && echo "Greater" || echo "Not greater or not a number"                                        
Not greater or not a number
```

So to fix your code, you could use

```
read o
while ! (( o > 3 )); do
    echo "wrong"
    read o
done
```

But I actually prefer [Walter A.'s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45909381/3266847) (rewritten to use `(( ))`):

```
while read o; do
    (( o > 3 )) && break
    echo "wrong"
done
```